# How can I invoke "scsi start stop" from command-line since gnome-disks seems to support this call?

Tags: command-line, disk, scsi

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Gnome-disk-utility has a button which invokes the `scsi start stop unit` command on a selected device. I'd like to invoke `scsi stop` for a device (in my case an empty SD-card adapter for micro-SD which I always leave in its slot) in a script/one line command so my system stops probing the empty adapter.

Gnome-disks depends on `udisks` and other modules for its functions. 
I'm trying to find which package is responsible for scsi calls and how I can invoke this outside of `gnome-disks-gui` (preferably without installing other packages).

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sg_start`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sg_start.8.html), which can be found in the [`sg3utils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sg3-utils) package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sg3utils
```

Comment: Thnx. The package `sg3-utils` contains more control functions but i needed just this one that the installed system already seemed to support.

Answer (score 0):

I looked further and found the answer to my own question.

When looking at my `syslog` i noticed that the module responsible for the command was `udisksd` which has a control utility `udisksctl` supporting the command `power-off [options]`. Since the action to be taken on `power-off` differs for different devices (sd*, hd* etc.) it parses the necessary commands automagicly sourcing the right library which for SCSI would be `libsgutils2-2` i assume. So installing other packages is not necessary for just this function. Since you can not rely on `/dev/sd*` to always pick the right device use something like `/dev/disk/by-id/`

My command-line became: `$ udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20090516388200000-0\:0`

When reinserting the adapter it gets detected and started automaticly